# C plus plus Kill process windows title

Tags: c++

I need a little of your help in this simple script. I am trying to create a script that run a "taskkill" by reading the windows title , but I dont know how to make it run in C++ . As I know in batch will be really easy

```
system("TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Notepad*"");
```

But when I try to do that in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
using namespace std;


system("TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Notepad*""); 


}
```

I am not able to compile it! I got this in DevC++

> [Error] expected ')' before 'WINDOWTITLE'

I am sure that the problem is set on that "_" needed to be able to run Windowstitle , but without that it will not work.

Any advice?

Thanks !

Comment: The syntax highlighting does a pretty good job of explaining why.

Comment: @chris: Hah, I was just about to say the same -- debugging by posting!

Comment: @KerrekSB, Shouldn't the IDE do that as well? Been a long, long time since I've used Dev, but even then, the WYSIWYG would, and noticing that it messes up on quotation marks might lead someone to search how to use those in strings.

Comment: @chris: Don't know, I don't use IDEs...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escape the quotation marks:

```
system("TASKKILL /F /FI \"WINDOWTITLE eq Notepad*\""); 
//                     ^^^                      ^^^
```